# Specifying variable outside a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following for loop written to sum all numbers in a list. I'm aware there is a `sum` function in python.

```
tot = 0
var = 5
for num in range(1, var + 1):
    tot += num
print tot
```

When I try to intialise `tot` within the for loop, it gives an incorrect answer: i.e.

```
var = 5
for num in range(1, var + 1):
    tot = 0
    tot += num
print tot
```

Any reason for this? Please note, I'm a beginner in python.

Comment: with every loop iteration you reset the value of tot to 0

Comment: In the second snippet, you are reassigning `0` to `tot` on every iteration.So  you should always get `var` as end result.

Comment: I see, thanks for this. So this means the first code is the correct way to do it.

Comment: "Correct" is subjective. The answer is correct. Your logic isn't.

Comment: I don't quite understand the reason for the down votes though-its a genuine question and I'm a beginner with python.

Comment: I love these petty SO fights over anonymous downvoters. Those saboteurs!

Comment: If you initialize it _within_ the `for` loop, so it gets initialized over-and-over. I think the oddest thing for me is that your profile says you're a research student...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, you reassign the value of `tot` to zero. Thus, `tot` will simply be `var` in the last iteration.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to post your answer.

Comment: By the way, you can just use `sum(range(1, var + 1))` instead of a loop.